# Facebook Like click showing URL for a fraction of a second

Tags: interface, facebook-like

I am using an iFrame version of Facebook Like. 
On Like click, sometimes, it shows the URL of the liked page, for a fraction of second.
After that, it shows the name of the person liking it.
Is there a way to prevent it from showing the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Like button is Facebook functionality and thus cannot be changed in anyway. You are better off [filing a bug with Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs) with deterministic repro steps so they can address the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks Niraj. I filed a bug with Facebook but apparently, my request is of very low priority to them